# Como probar metodos sin llamar a la base de datos en php

Tags: php, pruebas-unitarias, phpunit

tengo una duda estoy iniciando con las pruebas unitarias en php, estoy usando phpunit y hasta ahora he seguido la documentacion. Mi pregunta es al momento de hacer un assert con un metodo que implica modificar un registro en la base de datos

```
$this->assertEquals(true, $objUser->crearUsuario('dan2', 'daniel', 'larusso', 'larusso23@hotmail.com', 31245555, 'colador', '12-03-1999', 'Masculino'));
```

en esta linea estoy llamando un metodo que va a crear un registro en la base de datos cuando ejecuto la prueba me doy cuenta que tambien llama a la base de datos.

metodo del modelo usuario:

```
public function crearUsuario($usu, $nom, $ape, $corr, $cel, $cont, $fec, $sex){

  $consulta4 = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES(NULL,'$usu','$nom','$ape','$corr','$cel','$cont','$fec','$sex','')");

            if($consulta4->rowCount()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
```

¿Hay alguna forma de realizar este tipo de pruebas sin que se realize la accion a la base de datos? agradezco a la presona que pueda orientarme en este tema.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando creas el objeto $objUser en tu test, tendras una linea del tipo:

```
$objUser = new ObjUser($parametro1, $parametro2...)
```

entre los parametros, uno de ellos deberia ser el objeto `db`. (ya que luego internamente en tu metodo `crearUsuario` estas invocandolo con $this->db). Si no es db, sera uno parecido, que te genera el objeto db.

asi que en tu test, debes crear un mock del objeto db:

```
$mockDb = $this->getMockBuilder(DB::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
```

Luego, le indicas a ese mock que el metodo `query` te devuelva un array de resultados:

```
$devuelve = [];   <-- aqui llena el array que quieras devolver
$mockDb->method('query')
    ->willReturn($devuelve);
```

por ultimo, crea tu objeto ObjUser con el mock que has definido anteriormente, en la posicion que sea de tu constructor:

```
$objUser = new ObjUser($parametro1, $parametro2... $mockDb,...);
```

Listo. Ahora, cuando en tu test llames a un metodo que internamente llama a $this->db->query, este te va a devolver el array de `$devuelve` que hemos definido antes.